# How do I know if my tag wikis have been rejected?

Tags: soporte

From time to time I get into *tag edit frenzy* mode, and I edit and complete a good amount of the tags that have either no excerpt, no boy or both. I have no tag edit privileges, so they have to wait for approval.

I'm doing another round and I'm positive that some tags I edited and completed way back then now have no excerpt nor description.

How can I know if my tag edits have been discarded or if there's something wrong that I need to correct?

I think I'm doing quite a lot of word completing them and if for some reason part of that work is not suitable I would like to learn why and correct what's wrong. I feel like there is no feedback mechanism for those contributions. If users need to use "trial and error" eventually they'll get either bored or upset and will stop working to improve the site.

Comment: I've been approving the vast majority of them.  But after I approve them, they're still not showing up so it probably requires at least one or two others to approve.

Comment: @guifa, you are right. In my review panel they appear as approved by two people. Haven't seen anything rejected nor controversial (see my answer to this question) but I wonder how this would be for somebody who doesn't have the privileges. Thank you for accepting them, BTW.

Comment: I actually want them to show up because I found a few typo, but my only two options were accept or reject, not "make minor edit and accept"

Comment: should be good to know how many people need to approved the tag edition or creation. it's seem that just @guifa and I are approving your tag's editons

Comment: @EmilioGort, lets also have in mind that there are not that many users beyond the 4K points here (with privileges enough to do so). I think it needs just two people to approve them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer my own question, at least partially.

If you have enough privileges, when you click "review" you have a "tools" tab near the "review" tab. Among the functionality available on this tab is "suggested edit stats", where you can check your edits, and see if they are approved or rejected. To te right you could also see the categories for "Suggested Edits", which are: all, approved, **rejected, controversial**, anonymous and improved.

So with the "rejected" and "controversial" categories you should have some help to figure out if something is wrong with your edits.